# Show task in ALT+TAB but not show in taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

I have two windows (WPF), the `MainWindow` and `Window1`, from `MainWindow` user can show the `Window1` as Modal Window:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var win = new Window1();
    win.Owner = this;
    win.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
    win.ShowInTaskbar = false;

    win.ShowDialog();
}
```

So I hope the Window1 doesn't show in taskbar, but this application can be seen in <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, any simple way to achieve this?

And from the research, it seems if application task can not be seen in <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> unless setting `ShowInTaskbar = true`, but I also don't want the `Window1` show in task bar.

When I check Visual Studio, click Help/About the modal dialog shows, and it didn't show in taskbar, but also the Visual Studio main window can be seen in <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, that's what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your `WindowStyle`. ToolWindow skip `Alt+Tab`
Just remove this line

```
win.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
```

or replace other style

If you want to use Window1 like tool. You just use `win.Show()`

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right, simply remove the `WindowStyle` can solve my problem. But the reason why I use `TooWindow` is that I want to remove the left icon in the Window, and `ToolWindow` can meet my requirement. And I think I have to use `ShowDialog`. So, any approach can achieve this?

Comment: `WindowStyle.None` is No icon and no Titlebar

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a new XAML Window and put ShowInTaskbar="False" on your XAML code of your New Window.